# Electrum error "server did not answer" when trying to send?

Tags: electrum

I am now getting this error.  Several sites discuss it, but they are all fairly old.  I have restarted electrum, and restarted the computer.  Selecting a different server either doesn't help, or it stops being connected.  Have tried to upgrade, but get an error that apparently is a legit bug.